# How to register Nestjs project with Spring Eureka

Tags: spring-boot, nestjs, netflix-eureka

I'am begginer with nest js and I would like to know how to implement eureka client discovery with nest js. I saw this dependency https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-eureka exists but there is no example of any implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Eureka Module to `app.module` imports:[]

```
EurekaModule.forRoot({
    disable: false,
    disableDiscovery: false,
    eureka: {
        host: process.env.EUREKA_HOST || 'eureka-server',
        port: process.env.EUREKA_PORT || 80,
        servicePath: '/eureka/apps',
        maxRetries: 10,
        requestRetryDelay: 10000,
    },
    service: {
        name: 'nest-service',
        port: parseInt(process.env.APP_PORT) || 3000,
    },
}),
```